# Can I simulate keypress event in vscode search box?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would love to somehow simulate typing `.*` in search bar in vscode by pressing `space`, making at least some workaround for fuzzy matching, is it possible somehow?

I found this command for typing, and tried it in my vscode extension (basic helloworld):

```js
  vscode.commands.executeCommand("type", { text: ".*" });
```

and then in keybindings.json config, I added this:

```js
    {
        "key": "space",
        "command": "extension.helloWorld",
        "when": "editorFocus && findInputFocussed"
    },
```

It typing `.*` on space pressing, but not in search bar - but in active editor window.

Answer (score 1):

That does not seem to be possible. There was a feature request at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/104832 which requested this feature. The request was unfortunately closed.